# JS vendor published files are not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel filemanager:

https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation

When I publish public from vendor everything works except JS files.

It still uses js files from vendor instead from public.

**I tried:**

- Run composer dumpautoload
- Clear all cache after any code changes, both in laravel and browser.

> Deleting js files from public directory does nothing but when I delete
>   them from vendor folder it says they are missing even when they are in
>   public directory..

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out that only one js/script was not used from public but vendor directory.

Inside vendor views directory `=> index.blade.php` I found:

```
<script>{!! \File::get(base_path('vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/public/js/script.js')) !!}</script>
{{-- Use the line below instead of the above if you need to cache the script. --}}
{{-- <script src="{{ asset('vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/script.js') }}"></script> --}}
```

And commented vendor script and uncommented public one.

Now it works.